# Ansible yum: can't loop items for localfiles correctly

Tags: installation, ansible, yum

When doing a task like this in order to install local packages (*a la* yum localinstall):

```
- name: Install local packages
  yum:
    name="/my/path/{{ item }}"
    state=installed
  with_items: list_of_packages
```

Where list_of_packages is defined in vars/main.yml as:

```
---
list_of_packages:
  - package1.rpm
  - package2.rpm
  ...
```

Yum tries to be smart and put all items in one command but ends only adding the path to the first package:

> REMOTE_MODULE yum name="/my/path/package1.rpm,package2.rpm" state=installed

And obviously fails not finding the second package

I've tried adding the path inside like: `{{ "/my/path/"+item }}` and keeps doing the same.

Is there a way besides duplicating "list_of_packages" with the base path added? (workaround i'm using)

EDIT: Detailed test playbook (ansible version 1.9.2):

```
# cat playbooks/testlocalinstall.yml
---
- hosts: all:!localhost

  vars:

    list_of_packages:
      - oracleasmlib-2.0.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
      - oracleasm-support-2.1.8-1.el6.x86_64.rpm


  tasks:

    - name: Install Packages
      yum: name=/software/{{ item }} state=installed
      with_items: list_of_packages
```

Result:

```
# ansible-playbook playbooks/testlocalinstall.yml -i inventory/myinv -vvv

PLAY [all:!localhost] *********************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
<testmachine> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: root on PORT 22 TO testmachine
<testmachine> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<testmachine> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441783338.15-74757921814888 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441783338.15-74757921814888'
<testmachine> PUT /tmp/tmp_955vP TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441783338.15-74757921814888/setup
<testmachine> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441783338.15-74757921814888/setup; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441783338.15-74757921814888/ >/dev/null 2>&1'
ok: [testmachine]

TASK: [Install Packages] ******************************************************
<testmachine> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: root on PORT 22 TO testmachine
<testmachine> REMOTE_MODULE yum name=/software/oracleasmlib-2.0.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm,oracleasm-support-2.1.8-1.el6.x86_64.rpm state=installed
<testmachine> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441783339.35-66981904309720 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441783339.35-66981904309720'
<testmachine> PUT /tmp/tmpF0hiqP TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441783339.35-66981904309720/yum
<testmachine> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python -tt /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441783339.35-66981904309720/yum; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441783339.35-66981904309720/ >/dev/null 2>&1'
failed: [testmachine] => (item=oracleasmlib-2.0.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm,oracleasm-support-2.1.8-1.el6.x86_64.rpm) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": "oracleasmlib-2.0.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm,oracleasm-support-2.1.8-1.el6.x86_64.rpm", "rc": 0, "results": []}
msg: No Package file matching 'oracleasm-support-2.1.8-1.el6.x86_64.rpm' found on system

msg:
No Package file matching 'oracleasm-support-2.1.8-1.el6.x86_64.rpm' found on system

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/root/testlocalinstall.retry

testmachine          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Adding the path to each package on the list works fine

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce this issue:

- 3 packages where downloaded using `--downloadonly` yum option ( [link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154) )
- Ansible verbose mode showed the same result - only first package has path prefix, but installation works.

Please try this:

1. Check you Ansible version - there is a chance that bug exists in versions prior to 1.9.2 ( version I was testing on )
2. Yum cannot find dependancies for package list you provided - make sure all packages downloaded with `yum --downloadonly` are in the list. They should be stated explicitly together with target packages.
3. As a workaround you can create local yum repository using template module, that points to the same folder `/my/path/`. This repo should be disabled by default. Enable this repo only during `yum` task with `enablerepo` ( [link](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html) )

Here is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all

  vars:

    list_of_packages:
      - nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64.rpm
      - telnet-0.17-48.el6.x86_64.rpm
      - screen-4.0.3-18.el6.x86_64.rpm


  tasks:

    - name: Install Packages
      yum: name=/vagrant/{{ item }} state=installed
      with_items: list_of_packages
```

Output:

```
vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ sudo ansible-playbook -vvv -c local -i "localhost," test.yml

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
<localhost> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<localhost> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441656987.66-146848178907207 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441656987.66-146848178907207']
<localhost> PUT /tmp/tmp7TIwxU TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441656987.66-146848178907207/setup
<localhost> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441656987.66-146848178907207/setup; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-    tmp-1441656987.66-146848178907207/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [Install Packages] ******************************************************
<localhost> REMOTE_MODULE yum name=/vagrant/nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64.rpm,telnet-0.17-48.el6.x86_64.rpm,screen-4.0.3-18.el6.x86_64.rpm,lftp-4.0.9-6.el6.x86_64.rpm state=installed
<localhost> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441656987.78-72871194424865 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441656987.78-72871194424865']
<localhost> PUT /tmp/tmpTy7Al1 TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441656987.78-72871194424865/yum
<localhost> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python -tt /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441656987.78-72871194424865/yum; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-    tmp-1441656987.78-72871194424865/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
changed: [localhost] => (item=nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64.rpm,telnet-0.17-48.el6.x86_64.rpm,screen-4.0.3-18.el6.x86_64.rpm,lftp-4.0.9-6.el6.x86_64.rpm) => {"changed": true, "item": "nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64.rpm,    telnet-0.17-48.el6.x86_64.rpm,screen-4.0.3-18.el6.x86_64.rpm,lftp-4.0.9-6.el6.x86_64.rpm", "msg": "", "rc": 0, "results": ["Loaded plugins: fastestmirror\nSetting up Install Process\nExamining /vagrant/    nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64.rpm: nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64\nMarking /vagrant/nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed\nLoading mirror speeds from cached hostfile\n * base: mirror.isoc.org.il\n * epel: mirror.de.    leaseweb.net\n * extras: mirror.isoc.org.il\n * updates: mirror.isoc.org.il\nExamining telnet-0.17-48.el6.x86_64.rpm: 1:telnet-0.17-48.el6.x86_64\nMarking telnet-0.17-48.el6.x86_64.rpm to be     installed\nExamining screen-4.0.3-18.el6.x86_64.rpm: screen-4.0.3-18.el6.x86_64\nMarking screen-4.0.3-18.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed\nResolving Dependencies\n--> Running transaction check\n--->     Package nc.x86_64 0:1.84-24.el6 will be installed\n---> Package screen.x86_64 0:4.0.3-18.el6 will be installed\n---> Package telnet.x86_64 1:0.17-48.el6 will be installed\n--> Finished Dependency     Resolution\n\nDependencies Resolved\n\n================================================================================\n Package    Arch       Version            Repository                           Size\n================================================================================\nInstalling:\n nc         x86_64     1.84-24.el6        /nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64          109 k\n screen         x86_64     4.0.3-18.el6       /screen-4.0.3-18.el6.x86_64     795 k\n telnet     x86_64     1:0.17-48.el6      /telnet-0.17-48.el6.x86_64      109 k\n\nTransaction     Summary\n================================================================================\nInstall       3 Package(s)\n\nTotal size: 1.0 M\nInstalled size: 1.0 M\nDownloading Packages:\nRunning     rpm_check_debug\nRunning Transaction Test\nTransaction Test Succeeded\nRunning Transaction\n\r  Installing : nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64                                        1/3 \n\r  Installing : 1:telnet-    0.17-48.el6.x86_64                                  2/3 \n\r  Installing : screen-4.0.3-18.el6.x86_64                                   3/3 \n\r  Verifying  : screen-4.0.3-18.el6.    x86_64                                   1/3 \n\r  Verifying  : 1:telnet-0.17-48.el6.x86_64                                  2/3 \n\r  Verifying  : nc-1.84-24.el6.    x86_64                                        3/3 \n\nInstalled:\n  nc.x86_64 0:1.84-24.el6                screen.x86_64 0:4.0.3-18.el6           \n  telnet.x86_64 1:0.17-48.el6               \n\nComplete!\n"]}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird it fails for me, can't put my test in a comment, i'm updating the question

Answer (score 1):

Ansible documentation does not recommend using loops (`with_items` is also a loop) with package management modules, including [`yum`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html):

> When used with a `loop:` each package will be processed individually, it is much more efficient to pass the list directly to the `name` option.

As for the original issue, the module documentation contains the following explanation:

> In versions prior to 1.9.2 this module installed and removed each package given to the yum module separately. This caused problems when packages specified by filename or url had to be installed or removed together. In 1.9.2 this was fixed so that packages are installed in one yum transaction. However, if one of the packages adds a new yum repository that the other packages come from (such as epel-release) then that package needs to be installed in a separate task. This mimics yum’s command line behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `with_items` I believe it is expecting a yaml list, not a comma-delimited list.

```
 name: install local packages   
 yum: name="/my/path/{{ item }}" state=installed  
 with_items:
      - package1.rpm
      - package2.rpm
      - package3.rpm
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that  list_of_packages is a YAML list on a vars file. I think it has to do more with yum module trying to be smart instead of sequentially installing the packages and calling yum N times.