Ansible (installation of rpm files and outputting whether the installation was successful or not one by one in a loop)
So there are a bunch of rpm files in a directory which we need to install using the command "/usr/bin/yum install $i -y" where $i is the respective rpm file. And at the same time if the return code was not 0 i.e if the installation was not successful we would like to output that message. How do i incorporate both installation and outputting message part into one loop in Ansible.
My example Ansible script without the message part :
-name: Installation of rpm files in a loop

shell: /usr/bin/yum install {{ rpm_files }} -y

args:

 chdir: {{install_dir}}

with_items:

 - the rpm files

loop_control:

 loop_var: rpm_files


It is recommended to use yum module – Manages packages with the yum package manager.
By using this one define the Desired state and "idempotency". Furthermore, according Parameter: name

You can also pass a URL or a local path to an RPM file (using state=present). To operate on several packages this can accept a comma separated string of packages or (as of 2.0) a list of packages.

So there also no need for loop according the Notes.

How can I print my message if the installation was successful?

Since every module has Return Values, just Register a variable and use the debug module – Print statements during execution afterwards.

So as there are multiple files involved, how can i print my message if the installation was successful for each rpm file one by one. Also so using yum module in the name section i can declare multiple local paths of the files right?

@Debdas yum module can (and should) be used with a list of packages passed to name parameter directly rather than in a loop. That applies to the local paths, too. There's no need to output any messages as Ansible will stop with an error automatically if something goes wrong. And IMHO it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/78240402/16417367
